# Creating a graph using networkx for each sentence

Tags: python, graph, networkx

I want to create a graph for each sentence in the sentence_list. If the sentence contains a proper noun then that word is appended to the subject_list. If the word is  a common noun then the word is appended to the object_list and if the word is a verb then it is appended to the verb_list.
How can I create a graph separately for each sentence?

```
sentence_list=['Tom drinks milk', 'Jack plays cricket', 'Tim ate rice']

tag_list=[Tom:'NP',drinks:'VF',milk:'NN',plays:'VF',cricket:'NN',ate:'VF',rice:'NN',Tim:'NP', Jack:'NP']
subject_list=[]
object_list=[]
verb_list=[]

newDict = {}
for sent in sentence_list:
   for line in tag_list:
       k,v = line.strip().split(':')
       newDict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
       if v=='NP':
          subject_list.append(k)
          print('SUBJECT:',subject_list)
       if v=='NN':
          object_list.append(k)
          print('OBJECT',object_list)                 
       if v=='VF':
        verb_list.append(k)
        print('VERB',verb_list)
 import networkx as nx
 import matplotlib.pyplot as pl


 labels={}
 graph = nx.Graph()

 for subject in subject_list:
     s=subject.decode('utf-8')
     graph.add_node(s)
     labels[s]=s


 for obj in object_list:
     b=obj.decode('utf-8')
     graph.add_node(b)
     labels[b]=b

 for verb in verb_list:
     v=verb.decode('utf-8')
     graph.add_node(v)
     labels[v]=v

 for s,o,v in subject_list,object_list,verb_list:
     graph.add_edge(subject_list[s],object_list[o])
     graph.add_edge(object_list[o],verb_list[v])


      pos=nx.spring_layout(graph)
 nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos=pos, labels=labels)
 pl.show()
```

[Expected Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QVn1V.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
sentence_list=['Tom drinks milk', 'Jack plays cricket', 'Tim ate rice']

tag_list={'Tom':'NP','Tim':'NP','Jack':'NP','drinks':'VF','milk':'NN','plays':'VF','cricket':'NN','ate':'VF','rice':'NN'}
tag_list_keys = tag_list.keys()
subject_list=[]
object_list=[]
verb_list=[]

def classify(item):
    if item in tag_list_keys:
        if tag_list[item] == 'NP': subject_list.append(item)
        if tag_list[item] == 'NN': object_list.append(item)
        if tag_list[item] == 'VF': verb_list.append(item)



def extract(item):
    item_split = item.split(' ')
    map(classify, item_split)

map(extract, sentence_list)

print('SUBJECT:',subject_list)
print('OBJECT',object_list)                 
print('VERB',verb_list)

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

G = nx.Graph()
for i in range(3):
    G.add_node(object_list[i])
    G.add_node(verb_list[i])
    G.add_node(subject_list[i])
    G.add_edge(verb_list[i],object_list[i])
    G.add_edge(subject_list[i],verb_list[i])
nx.draw(G, with_labels= True)
plt.show()
```

hopefully, this works out for you.

Answer (score 0):

What exactly the error you are getting and what is the desired output you want.
I just modified your code a bit and its working for me. Please review below code.

```
sentence_list=['Tom drinks milk', 'Tom plays cricket', 'Tom ate rice']

tag_list=['Tom:NP','drinks:VF','milk:NN','plays:VF','cricket:NN','ate:VF','rice:NN']
subject_list=[]
object_list=[]
verb_list=[]

newDict = {}
for sent in sentence_list:
   for line in tag_list:
       print (line)
       k,v = line.strip().split(':')
       newDict[k.strip()] = v.strip()
       if v=='NP':
          subject_list.append(k)
          print('SUBJECT:',subject_list)
       elif v=='NN':
          object_list.append(k)
          print('OBJECT',object_list)                 
       elif v=='VF':
        verb_list.append(k)
        print('VERB',verb_list)

import networkx as nx
import matplotlib.pyplot as pl


labels={}
graph = nx.Graph()

for subject in subject_list:
    s=(subject)
    graph.add_node(s)
    labels[s]=s


for obj in object_list:
    b=obj
    graph.add_node(b)
    labels[b]=b

for verb in verb_list:
    v=verb
    graph.add_node(v)
    labels[v]=v

graph.add_edge(subject_list[0],object_list[0])
graph.add_edge(object_list[0],verb_list[0])

graph.add_edge(subject_list[1],object_list[1])
graph.add_edge(object_list[1],verb_list[1])
pos=nx.spring_layout(graph)
nx.draw_networkx(graph, pos=pos, labels=labels)
pl.show()
```

Comment: I tried the above code and I'm getting a graph (I've put the link in the question above). I'm trying to create three graphs since there are three sentences in the list. The graphs should be represented in this  manner: Tom->drinks->milk, Tom->plays->cricket, Tom->ate->rice.  It should be in the form of subject->verb->object

Comment: @ParulGargplease check this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55553495/how-to-draw-a-graph-for-each-sentence-in-the-document-based-on-the-tags-assigned